# Dijkstra's algorithm on a graph whose edge weights are limited

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

Suppose we want to run Dijkstra's algorithm on a graph whose edge weights are integers in the
range `{1,2,...,W}`, where W is a relatively small number. How to find the shortest path from vertex `s` to `t` in `O((|V|+|E|)logW)`?

I encountered this problem from the book Algorithms by S. Dasgupta, C. Papadimitriou and U. Vazirani. I could prove that if we implement the Dijkstra's algorithm as before, at each iteration the range of the distances for nodes in the priority queue would be within `W`. However, since priority queues do not have the property to put elements with same weights into the same bucket, this observation does not directly lead to a solution to the problem.

Could anyone give me some hints on how to go one step further to make the bounded range `W` work for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmh, probably the sorting of the priority queue could be faster via counting/radix sort. Also updating (remove+insert) an element could now be faster as the queue could be an array of arrays (or sorted map of arrays)

Comment: The solution is given (the _Bounded Integer Edge Weights_ problem) in the lecture [Courses.MIT](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/rec/rec16.pdf). Furthermore, its time complexity is $O(|V| + |E|)$ in linear.

Answer (score 1):

How many different numbers you can have in your priority queue?

**Solution**
Note that after you extract the node with size X(and now you relax..)
the max size it can reach is X+W.
all the other numbers are bigger then X (because you took the min from the queue)
so you have only O(W) different numbers in the queue,so you can use it as a binary heap and then every step will took O(logW) and all together will be:
(V+E)logW.

Answer (score 0):

we denote the last popmin weight is D, so at any time the keys in priority queue are in range of {D, D+1, \ldots, D+C} (because D has just been updated, we denote the pop vertical as v   ,then v may relax some vertical adjacent to it denote as v, because the distance from the source to v is D and the edge weight is less than C so the new distance from source to v at most is  D+C  )

we use priority queue the same as before, and the priority queue element is bucket. By our analysis,the max number of elements in the priority queue is C+1

now we analyze some operations in this datastructure

> popmin:because the max number of elements in the priority queue is C+1,so  popmin takes O(\log(C+1))
>
> insert&update:   because the max number of elements in the priority queue is C+1,so insert&update takes O(\log(C+1))

and we find the Dijkstra algorithm take update |E| rounds ,each update takes O(\log(C+1)) ,so in all the update tales O(|E|*O(\log(C+1)))

and find min |V| takes rounds,each popmin takes O(\log(C+1)) ,so in all the update tales O(|V|*O(\log(C+1)))

so this algorithm in all takes O(|E|*O(\log(C+1)))+O(|V|*O(\log(C+1)))=O(\log (C+1)(|V|+|E|))=O((\log C)(|V|+|E|))